# How to pass more than 1 data type through an Intent in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

Hello Im trying to pass more than 1 type of data through an intent. I would like to show the title and then a web link. It only shows one at a time but not both. Can any one help me please?

```
private void shareWithOtherApps()
{
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("text/plain");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, title);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, url);
    try
    {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share News"));
        //startActivity(i);
    }
    catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex)
    {
        //ToastHelper.MakeShortText("app have not been installed.");
    }
}`
```

[Emulator img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHKna.png)

Comment: You cannot force developers of other apps to use both `EXTRA_TITLE` and `EXTRA_TEXT`. They are free to do whatever they want.

Comment: Oh...  So how could I pass they title and the link?

Comment: You already are passing both the title and the link. Your code is fine.

Comment: For some reason on the emulator, its only showing the link not the title.

Comment: Most likely, it has to do with the app, not the emulator. You are asking somebody else's app to send something. It is up to that app's developers to handle your request. If they do not want to use both the title and text, **that is their decision, as it is their app, not yours**.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your input.

Comment: Intent.EXTRA_TITLE is not meant to send anything to the other app. Instead it gives the activity chooser a title. You could use something like "Which app do you want to open to send this image?".